# how to make in first row collectionView horizontal and the bottom collectionView grid

Tags: swift, uikit

I want to achieve what is in the picture but I'm debating whether to make the collection views inside tableView with different cells (I'm not sure how to do it)
or scroll view and insert 2 collection views

link to picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/if2pH.png

Comment: just use 1 ``UICollectionView`` with ``UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout``. Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Comment: @bewithyou, you should provide your answer as an answer so the OP can accept it. That way future readers can tell that a correct answer was provided.

Comment: Dear @DuncanC, thank you for your reply. I've updated my answer as detail for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 14+, Apple has provide [UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout) as a type of `UICollectionView` layout design for new **Modern Collection Views**.

[This example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) is provided by Apple on how to use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` and `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` in the new modern way.

For your question, you just need 1 `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` will solved your problem.

I will customize from [Apple's example above](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) to make a code preview how to get your desire output.

Step 1: Make `TextCell` is `UICollectionViewCell` to describe

```swift
class TextCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label = UILabel()
    static let reuseIdentifier = "text-cell-reuse-identifier"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not implemnted")
    }

}

extension TextCell {
    func configure() {
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        let inset = CGFloat(10)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: inset),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -inset),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: inset),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -inset)
            ])
    }
}
```

Step 2: Make an enum as list of layout you want. In here I make one is horizontal list, 1 is list grid with 3 items and 1 is list grid with 5 items for you to easier understand.

```swift
enum SectionLayoutKind: Int, CaseIterable {
    case horizontalList, grid5, grid3
    var columnCount: Int {
        switch self {
        case .grid3:
            return 3

        case .grid5:
            return 5

        case .horizontalList:
            return 1
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3: Combine to `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` and `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` in your `ViewController`.

So the full code is this

```swift
class DesiredViewController: UIViewController {
    // make an enum of list kind cell as you want to decribe
    enum SectionLayoutKind: Int, CaseIterable {
        case horizontalList, grid5, grid3
        var columnCount: Int {
            switch self {
            case .grid3:
                return 3

            case .grid5:
                return 5

            case .horizontalList:
                return 1
            }
        }
    }

    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<SectionLayoutKind, Int>! = nil
    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Exptected Output"
        configureHierarchy()
        configureDataSource()
    }
}

extension DesiredViewController {
    /// - Tag: PerSection
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex: Int,
            layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

            guard let sectionLayoutKind = SectionLayoutKind(rawValue: sectionIndex) else { return nil }
            
            let section: NSCollectionLayoutSection
            if sectionLayoutKind == .horizontalList {
                let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
                let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
                item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
                let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.28), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.2))
                let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
                section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
                section.interGroupSpacing = 10
                section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuousGroupLeadingBoundary
                section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
                return section
                
            }
            let columns = sectionLayoutKind.columnCount

            // The group auto-calculates the actual item width to make
            // the requested number of columns fit, so this widthDimension is ignored.
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                                 heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 2, leading: 2, bottom: 2, trailing: 2)

            let groupHeight = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalWidth(0.2)
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                                  heightDimension: groupHeight)
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: columns)

            section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 20, bottom: 20, trailing: 20)
            return section
        }
        return layout
    }
}

extension DesiredViewController {
    func configureHierarchy() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func configureDataSource() {
        let textCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<TextCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, identifier) in
            // Populate the cell with our item description.
            cell.label.text = "\(identifier)"
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .cornflowerBlue
            cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = SectionLayoutKind(rawValue: indexPath.section)! == .grid5 ? 8 : 0
            cell.label.textAlignment = .center
            cell.label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<SectionLayoutKind, Int>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            // Return the cell of your choose
            // in here I use just 1 cell is text cell but you can choose as any custom cell you design for each section
            return SectionLayoutKind(rawValue: indexPath.section)! == .horizontalList ?
            collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: textCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier) :
            collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: textCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier)
        }

        // initial data
        let itemsPerSection = 10
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<SectionLayoutKind, Int>()
        SectionLayoutKind.allCases.forEach {
            snapshot.appendSections([$0])
            let itemOffset = $0.rawValue * itemsPerSection
            let itemUpperbound = itemOffset + itemsPerSection
            snapshot.appendItems(Array(itemOffset..<itemUpperbound))
        }
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}

extension DesiredViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And this is the result

[image: The Result]

Comment: Wow. Excellent, thorough answer! (Voted.)