# How to adjust layout of UICollectionView which is embedded inside a UITableViewCell when ViewController is loaded?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, ipad, uicollectionview

In my iPad app, I have a `UICollectionView` with dynamic height embedded inside a `UITableViewCell`. My issue is when tableView is loaded, the collection view cells are not adjusted properly but as soon as I rotate or change screen orientation, the layout gets adjusted properly.

This is what I am getting at startup:

[image]

I am using collectionView's width to calculate width of these cells but I think when tableView is loaded, collectionView inside tableView cell has no proper layout. And this is correct layout after rotating app which I want at startup too:

[image]
[image]

This is my main `cellForRowAt` method for `tableView` in main `ViewController`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        // To invalidate layout when screen orientation changes
        if let layout = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.invalidateLayout()
        }
        cell.heighCollectionView.constant = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
        
        return cell
    }
```

And im just reloading tableView when Screen Orientation changes:

```
 override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

This is how im calculating layout of the CollectionView Cells:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
            let width = self.collectionView.frame.size.width
            let height = width / 2
            return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        }
        else {
            let width = (self.collectionView.frame.size.width - 10) / 2
            let height = width / 2
            return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        }
    }
```

And in `CustomTableViewCell` subclass, inside `awakeFromNib()`, I am just setting delegate and datasource of collectionView:

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
```

My issue is only when View Controller is loaded, how do I set proper layout for `collectionView` when its first loaded?

In case you need to see full code, here is the link for the repo: https://github.com/shwaitkumar/RotateCollectionViewInsideTableViewCell.git

Comment: How about using ``UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`` with only 1 ``UICollectionView``? Check my answer in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74419857/how-to-make-in-first-row-collectionview-horizontal-and-the-bottom-collectionview/74421620#74421620

Comment: @bewithyou will I need to replace my whole tableView with CollectionView then? Later I do want to add a stretchy header and other collection view inside this tableView cell. With this I think I will need 1 collectionView to handle all that but will I be able to add stretchy header and stuff?

Comment: Yes just 1 collectionView only. But for me if you want to keep your code at current code. Try remove ``cell.layoutIfNeeded()``

Comment: @bewithyou that did not work. I will give it a read in couple of hours and will see if I should proceed with it. This seems like a good approach, its just that I don't have much time to learn anything new

Comment: Dear Mel, can you give me a github repo on this error. Seems interesting. Your post is not very clear for the error you facing with

Comment: @bewithyou I edited my question and added link for the repo at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `init` ViewController, it get defaults value of height which not the height you calculate. Just at `viewDidAppear` reload data of your tableView to get the calculate height.

By the way, in `func tableView(_ tableView:, cellForRowAt indexPath:)` just for return cell so please remove calculate height there.

Code will be like this

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        
        //cell.layoutIfNeeded() // removed
        // To invalidate layout when screen orientation changes
        if let layout = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.invalidateLayout()
        }
        
        //cell.heighCollectionView.constant = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height // removed
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything worked smoothly however I had to add calculate height function after layout.invalidateLayout() because it wasn't updating cell height when screen orientation is changed